# Link scrollers in Android

Tags: android, scroll

What is the best way to make scrollviews move dependent of each other?

I have three scrollers (ScrollView/HorizontalScrollView), on vertical on the left and one horizontal on te top - e.g. like excel - where moving the left or center scroller should affect vertical scrolling in both and moving top or center should affect horizontal scrolling in both.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Have you considered a `Canvas` instead?